# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content error in Laravel 8.12

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I put this command:

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

and I have the error like in the title. I found that global update of composer can help and I did that but I  have this same message. Another post said that it could remove composer.lock but it doesn't help me too. How can I solve my problem?

@Edit

I cant' show you all error so look at this error message

```
    Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
    ./composer.json has been updated
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
    Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
    
      Problem 1
        - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v8.16.1
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v8.16.1
        - laravel/ui 2.x-dev requires illuminate/filesystem ^7.0 -> 
//...

        - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v8.16.1, required as ^8.12) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.16.1].
        - Installation request for laravel/ui ^2.4 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[2.x-dev, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.5.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Please can you show the whole error.

Comment: please post the full error given after executing this command

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you know there is `laravel/breeze`? but you can't use that version of `laravel/ui` with Laravel 8

Comment: for me, updating the composer from version 1.9 to 2 ^ solved this same problem

    php composer.phar self-update

Answer (score 1):

Laravel ui v2.4 is not compatible with Laravel 8.x

With Laravel 8.x the compatible version is 3.x and you are using Laravel  v8.16.1 as per the error. So you must `composer require laravel/ui` or use `"laravel/ui": "^3.0"` in your composer.json and run composer update

It's clearly mentioned on their github repo https://github.com/laravel/ui

Answer (score 0):

This error happening because you are using `Laravel 8`. I had the same problem and I use composer require `Laravel/ui`. This will update your ui to version 3.2 and it will work fine.